# Sidekiq not processing queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis, sidekiq

What possible reasons can [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) prevent from processing jobs in the queue? The queue is full. The log file `sidekiq.log` indicates no activity at all. Thus the queue is full but the log is empty, and Sidekiq does not seem to process items. There seem to no worker processing jobs. Restarting Redis or flush it with [FLUSHALL](http://redis.io/commands/flushall) or [FLUSHDB](http://redis.io/commands/flushdb) has no effect. Sidekiq has been started with

```
bundle exec sidekiq -L log/sidekiq.log
```

and produces the following log file:

```
2013-05-30..Booting Sidekiq 2.12.0 using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {}
2013-05-30..Running in ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [i686-linux]
2013-05-30..See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2013-05-30..Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
```

How can you find out what went wrong? Are there any hidden log files?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The reason was in our case: Sidekiq may look for the wrong queue. By default Sidekiq uses a queue named "default". We used two different queue names, and defined them in config/sidekiq.yml

```
# configuration file for Sidekiq
:queues:
  - queue_name_1
  - queue_name_2
```

The problem is that this config file **is not automatically loaded** by default in your development environment (unlike `database.yml` or `thinking_sphinx.yml` for instance)  by a simple `bundle exec sidekiq` command. Thus we wrote our jobs in two certain queues, and Sidekiq was waiting for jobs in a third queue (the default one). You have to pass the path to the config file as a parameter through the `-C`or `--config` option:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml
```

or you can pass the queue names directly (no spaces allowed here after the comma):

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q queue_name_1,queue_name_2
```

To find the problem out it is helpful to pass the option `-v` or `--verbose` at the command line, too, or to use `:verbose: true` in the `sidekiq.yml` file. Everything which is defined in a config file is of course useless if the config file is not loaded.. Therefore make sure you are using the right config file first.

Comment: The issue for me was that my worker had `queue_as` set to a queue that wasn't in my `sidekiq.yml` file.

Comment: > or you can pass the queue names directly (no spaces allowed here after the comma):

Are you sure this is fine? Shoulden't be `sidekiq -q queue_name_1 -q queue_name_2`

Comment: the complete command should be like this 
`bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production`
along with this you should add this to your sidekiq.rb

`Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' }
end`

Comment: I don't know if it was true for the 2013, but in 2017 the sidekiq **do load** `/config/sidekiq.yml` automatically.

Comment: As Wojtek pointed out, the command line flag `-q queue_name_1,queue_name_2` is not correct. You need to use a dedicated `-q` flag for each queue (cf. [docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues)). Use commas followed by an integer to indicate queue weight. (I had attempted to correct the answer to this effect, but the edit was rejected.)

Answer (score 14):

If you have a `config/sidekiq.yml` check that all the queues are defined there, check this sample file: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/config.yml

If you are passing queue names in the command line or Procfile, something similar to

```
bin/sidekiq -q queue1 -q queue2
bundle exec sidekiq -q queue1 -q queue2
```

check that all your queues are defined there.

In case you are not sure about the names of your queues, you can figure it out with the following script:

```
require "sidekiq/api"
stats = Sidekiq::Stats.new
stats.queues
# {"production_mailers"=>25, "production_default"=>1}
```

Then, you can do things with the queues:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("production_mailers")
queue.count
queue.clear
```

Answer (score 11):

It took me hours to find out that I had set `config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "xxxxx_#{Rails.env}"`. The queue names in the settings look the same, but sidekiq looks for the queue with prefix.

### Wrong setting

`app/jobs/my_job.rb`

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
end
```

`config/sidekiq.yml`

```
:queues:
  - default
```

### Correct setting

`app/jobs/my_job.rb`

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
end
```

`config/sidekiq.yml`

```
:queues:
  - xxxxx_development_default
  - xxxxx_production_default
```

Comment: This is actually what helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was I had a configure_server but not configure_client in my initialiser, you must have both:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch('SIDEKIQ_REDIS_URL', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1') }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch('SIDEKIQ_REDIS_URL', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1') }
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, sidekiq was fine in development, but stuck in staging. It was human error on the capistrano's deploy configuration. I set the path for sidekiq.yml incorrectly in the Capfile (shared instead of current).

It failed silently:

```
# Capfile

# WRONG:
set :sidekiq_config, -> { File.join(shared_path, 'config', 'sidekiq.yml') }
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
# RIGHT:
set :sidekiq_config, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config', 'sidekiq.yml') }
```

Answer (score 3):

flushing redis worked for me.

WARNING: THIS WILL REMOVE ALL DATA IN YOUR REDIS DATABASE.

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Comment: Warning! if you don't know what this means beforehand take a note: "Delete all the keys of all the existing databases, not just the currently selected one" (https://redis.io/commands/FLUSHALL)

Answer (score 1):

I was banging my head against a brick wall on this for a while, my issue was that sidekiq required a newer version of redis-server. I ran "bundle exec sidekiq" and that revealed the error. Once I updated to a newer version of redis-server it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue. Turns out I had made a syntax error in my sidekiq.yml

Answer (score 1):

Spent at least two hours on this as well because queues and configuration and web UI were all fine ... the jobs were just not processed.
My issue was that the sidekiq-server was not running in my docker-compose setup even though it should have been started in the command-section here:

```
 sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'proddb'
      - 'redis'
    build: rails-app
    --> command: bundle exec sidekiq --environment ${RAILS_ENV} -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - './rails-app:/project'
      - '/project/tmp' # don't mount tmp directory
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=${REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ}
    networks:
      - backend
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I did not config my `initializers/sidekiq.rb` properly but even with the correct config, sidekiq was still not running enqueued jobs. I had to run `spring stop` on top of that and restarted everything and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem wherein the logs would show entries such as `INFO  Rails : queueing TestWorker (TestWorker)`.  However, the jobs would never get processed, and none of the answers in this question solved the issue.

The tl;dr to my solution is that [Sidekiq's Testing Client](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing) was getting unexpectedly triggered.

I eventually deduced that there is some "magic" going on underneath the surface that makes it difficult to discretely determine where/when/how the above testing trigger was getting configured, based on the following anecdote...

Running `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development` had the result that `Sidekiq::Testing.fake? == true`

However, running `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development_2` had the result that `Sidekiq::Testing.fake? == false`

^ The only difference between these 2 commands is that I renamed the `development` environment in `sidekiq.yml` to `development_2`, i.e. the same/equivalent environment was running with both commands (at least, presumably it would be the same environment if it wasn't for this inane "magic" under the hood).

I updated `sidekiq.rb` to explicitly toggle `Sidekiq::Testing` via the following:

```
sidekiq_testing_fake = false  # set this using env var, etc.
if sidekiq_testing_fake
  Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
elsif Sidekiq.constants.include?(:Testing)
  Sidekiq::Testing.disable!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had both a `redis-server` running and Redis.app's redis-server running, I killed the redis-server (and kept the Redis.app one)

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to work, but jobs sat in the queue:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q queue_name,1 -c 2
```

This fixed things for me (I removed the weight for the queue):

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q queue_name -c 2
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯